# I've been working on my introduction to C++ project which is to make a game of NIM

Tags: c++

I've been working on my introduction to C++ project which is to make a game of NIM. I've written program and I thought it should run smoothly but I've countered the following errors.

I know too much code but I couldn't figure out what is the issue that is stopping me from running the program.

I'm new to the programming word so be understanding if the issue is very simple.

thank you in advance.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F91R4.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int stonesNum;
char goFirst;
int turn = 0;                   // 0 = player, 1 = computer
int stonesRemove;

int main() {

do
{
    cout << "Enter number of starting stones:" << endl;
    cin >> stonesNum;

    cout << "Would you like to go first? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> goFirst;
        
    if (goFirst == 'y' || goFirst == 'Y') 
    {
        turn = 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        turn = 1;
    }
    
    while (stonesNum > 0)
    {
        
        if (turn == 0)
        {
            cout << "How many would you like to remove: 1 or 2?" << endl;
            cin >> stonesRemove;
            stonesNum = stonesNum - 1;
            cout << "The number of stones left is " << stonesNum << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (stonesNum % 3 == 0)
            {
                stonesNum = stonesNum - 2;
                cout << "The computer removes 2 stones." << endl;
                cout << "The number of stones left is " << stonesNum << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                stonesNum = stonesNum - 1;
                cout << "The computer removes 1 stones." << endl;
                cout << "The number of stones left is " << stonesNum << endl;
            }
        }
        
        if (stonesNum == 0)
        {
            if (turn == 0)
            {
                cout << "The computer wins!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "you won!" << endl;
            }
        }

    }

 }

return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Your do-statement doesn't have a closing while.

Comment: @JosephLarson I still don't know how to do that. please edit on my code to fix the problem

Comment: For while loops, it's either `while (condition) {...}` or `do  {...} while (condition);` See [`while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) and [`do/while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)

Comment: It's a bit unrelated but you should use -= operator instead of stonesNum = stonesNum - 1; Like stonesNum-=1;

Comment: @debanshudas: How about `--stonesNum;` instead?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes that will work too, but he uses -2 increment also, so it would seem somewhat discontinuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an ending while condition after your do loop. The syntax is :

```
do{
//do stuff here
}while(condition);
```

In your case the condition would be (stonesNum!=0)

OR

Do

```
if (stonesNum == 0)
        {
            if (turn == 0)
            {
                cout << "The computer wins!" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "you won!" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
```

and put condition (true)

You actually don't require the do loop at all, are you trying to loop the game endlessly? If so then you should put an appropriate prompt at the beginning and put condition (true) in the do loop.

The complete code:

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter number of starting stones:" << endl;
    cin >> stonesNum;

    cout << "Would you like to go first? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> goFirst;
        
    if (goFirst == 'y' || goFirst == 'Y') 
    {
        turn = 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        turn = 1;
    }
    
    while (stonesNum > 0)
    {
        
        if (turn == 0)
        {
            cout << "How many would you like to remove: 1 or 2?" << endl;
            cin >> stonesRemove;
            stonesNum = stonesNum - 1;
            cout << "The number of stones left is " << stonesNum << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (stonesNum % 3 == 0)
            {
                stonesNum = stonesNum - 2;
                cout << "The computer removes 2 stones." << endl;
                cout << "The number of stones left is " << stonesNum << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                stonesNum = stonesNum - 1;
                cout << "The computer removes 1 stones." << endl;
                cout << "The number of stones left is " << stonesNum << endl;
            }
        }
        
        

    }
    if (turn == 0)
            {
                cout << "The computer wins!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "you won!" << endl;
            }


 }while(true);
```